# Calling a URL and sending POST data

Tags: wordpress

You can call a URL and add query string data with this WordPress command:

```
add_query_arg()
```

What is the right way to call a URL and send POST data (instead of query string)?

Comment: What have you tried so far? Where are you stuck?

Comment: The current solution for my problem is that you would hit a submit button for a form. I want to directly redirect to the form action's url with POST data.

Comment: Please add all clarification to your question by editing it, along with the code you are currently using

Answer (score 0):

Ok that was an easy one:

https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/wp_remote_post/

```
wp_remote_post( string $url, array $args = array() )
```